# Change addAttributeToFilter in new products widget (Magento 1.9.0)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to edit this code

```
->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                )
          )
```

replacing with this

`->addAttributeToFilter('featured', array('is' => 1))`

in

**app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\New.php**

In `CMS -> PAGE` naturally I've my widget

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="16" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Now I didn't understand why if I change anything in New.php in my home page I have the same result. This filter doesn't working. Where I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the filter isn't working because you're using the flat product collection and your `featured` attribute doesn't have "Used in Product Listing" turned on.

Try this instead:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'featured', 'eq' => 1)));
```

Comment: you right!!! I'm using the flat product and flat category and now I enabled the "Used in Product Listing" and insert your code but the result don't change. I think that the file's path is correct but I don't understand it when try to delete the file I haven't errors. It's normal??? Other suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

**

### Solved!!! The solution is very easy!

**

> Don't edit the ***new products widget*** or change the magento's files, but
>   is better to create new cms static block. Follow this steps if you
>   wanna create your featured products.

**STEP 1**

Create new attribute in *Attribute -> Manage Attributes*

- Attribute Code: **featured**
- Scope: *Store View*
- Used in Product Listing: *Yes*

Manage Label / Options

- Admin: Featured products
- Default Store View: Featured products

Don't forget the *Manage Attribute Sets*

**STEP 2**

Copy your list.phtml from

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

or

> app\design\frontend\default\yourtemplate\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

**To**

> app\design\frontend\default\yourtemplate\template\catalog\product\listFeatured.phtml

Open listFeatured.phtml and find it:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Change with:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("featured");

// Check the attribute from a select or multiselect
if($attribute->usesSource()):

    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    $idValue = 0;

    //Save the option's Id  if the label is "Yes"
    foreach ($options as $option):          
        if ($option['label'] == "Yes"):
            $idValue = $option['value'];
        endif;
    endforeach;

endif;

$_productCollection = $_product->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('featured', $idValue) // Filter the collection   
->setPage(1,16); //show max 1 page for 16 rows
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
```

**STEP 3**

Create your *CMS Static Block*

- Block Title: *Featured*
- Identifier: *featuredprod*
- Status: *Enabled*
- Content: *`{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/listFeatured.phtml"}}`*

**STEP 4**

Insert in your *CMS -> Page* your *CMS Static Block*

**STEP 5**

Go to *Manage products* and edit your product changing the featured property.

**STEP 6**

Reindex the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
->addAttributeToFilter('featured', array('is' => 1))
```

with

```
->addAttributeToFilter('featured', array('eq' => 1))
```